# multiple values in a single submit

Tags: mysql

I've been searching google to find the code, but I can't find it. What I want to do is pretty simple, but I'm not php expert.

I want to insert multiple cities' name in a single press of submit button (if that is possible)

I have created a database with 2 tables: 'cities' and 'states'
and I have populated the states table

so I need two fields or boxes, one is for states, which is drop down 'select' box which already filled with states name, pulled from the database,

the other one is a cities field which a text type field (type="text").

I want to be able to type in multiple cities name, probably separated with ',' a comma, 
and with a single press of submit button, all the value will be inserted into mysql cities table and go on to the next state.

I know I need to create some sort of loop, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: what have your tried? Show us your effort??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *index.php (html):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="save.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name ="cities" value="">
            <input type="text" name ="state" value="">

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
     </body>
```

### *save.php:

```
<?php
/* -------include you db connection here ----*/

     if(isset($_POST['çities']) && $_POST['çities'] !='' && isset($_POST['state']) &&  $_POST['state'] !=''){

             $cities =  explode (',', $_POST['çities']);
             $n = count($cities);
             for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
             //Insert data
                    mysql_query("insert into `cities` (city,state) values  ('".$cities[$i]."','".$_POST['state']."') or die(mysql_error());

              }
```

}

?>

Comment: // Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$city = explode(',', $_POST['city']);

//create a loop
if(isset($_POST['city'])) {
 
 
 $city = explode(',', $_POST['city']);
 $n = count($city);
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(city_id, city, state_id) VALUES(NULL, '.$city.","', '4421')") or die(mysql_error());
 }
} if($result) {
   header('Location: index.html'); 
}     is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

First you create the input in the form like this:

```
<input type="text" name="cities"/>
```

And you then type: New York, New Jersey, San Francisco, Denver, etc.

Then on the .php file that receives the data (i'd guess it's a $_POST variable), so $_POST['cities'] then, you split it and loop:

```
// split the values by comma
$_POST['cities'] = explode(',',$_POST['cities']);

// loop the values
foreach($_POST['cities'] as $city) {

    // trim (delete white space at the end and start for safety)
    $city = trim($city);

    mysql_query("insert into `cities` ('city','state') values ('".$city.','".$_POST['state']."');

}
```

And done.

Comment: Y U NO `<input type="text" name="cities[]"/>`

Comment: wow thanks, but how can I pull the states name from the database and link it with the city's name

Comment: then you'd get $_POST['cities'][0] with value 'New York, New Jersey, San Francisco, Denver' and then loop it anyway

Comment: Do it in the original form, add an input or select with the state name (that's what the variable $_POST['state'] was for)

Comment: I guess the variable should be state, $state? how can I create a drop down menu for the state? how to insert or pull data from database table?

Comment: how if I want to use semicolon , ';' instead of comma? how can I get the state's data from the states table, and be able to link it with the city? probably with state_id? and I want it to stay selected after submit button pressed